# Unable to connect Tplink wifi with my HP Laptop

Tags: wireless, networking, hp

I am new to ubuntu. I am using Tp-link adsl router for wireless Internet connection. And Hp Sleek Book Laptop. 
The problem is internet works when i plug the `Lan` cable but not form wifi. 
I dont see any wifi connection list on wireless network. My wifi button on keyboard color  also shows wifi disabled and i it does not enable when i press that key. 
I research so much on the google but couldn't found the solution. 
here are my some command logs:

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 3290
01:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. Device 3298
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5229 (rev 01)
krishna@krishna:~/Downloads/wicd-1.7.2.4$ /var/log/udev
bash: /var/log/udev: Permission denied
krishna@krishna:~/Downloads/wicd-1.7.2.4$ sudo /var/log/udev
sudo: /var/log/udev: command not found
krishna@krishna:~/Downloads/wicd-1.7.2.4$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 3290
01:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. Device 3298
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5229 (rev 01)
```

**rfkill list all**

```
    0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
    1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

**sudo lshw -c network**

```
     *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Ralink corp.
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:92510000-9251ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 28:92:4a:52:3e:1f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.195.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: We don't need lsusb. Edit your question and remove that, include the result of following `sudo lshw -c network` & `rfkill list all`.  Please check this for any additional driver installation if detected by ubutnu.. [How do I install extra drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/q/47506). And check for hardware switches of wi-fi.

Comment: hello Web-E. Thanks for you reply i have edited my question according to your suggestion. I have pasted my logs on the question. I checked Additional Drivers. It doesn't show any list to update. Can you suggest me now what i have to do please.